# Can't VNC into my OS X machine from my Windows machine

Tags: windows-7, macos, home-networking, vnc, vncserver

I'm trying to access my OS X (Snow Leopard) machine from my Windows 7 machine. Both machines are within my local network I don't need outside access. I'm using Vine Server (OSXvnc) for OS X  and TightVNC Viewer for Windows, but TightVNC keeps telling me that the host is unreachable.

Any idea what could be wrong? how could I troubleshoot this kind of issue?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you check your firewalls?

Comment: Just solved the issue. For some reason Windows won't connect to my OSX vnc server unless I set a password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use the built in VNC in OSX?  I believe (not having a mac in front of me) that you go to System Preferences>Sharing>>Internet and Network  and turn on VNC.  Give it a password.
When doing this, I have never had an issue connecting to a OSX box.

Comment: I did that and even turned off the OSX firefwall, still get "connection timed out" message from my windows machine.